# unity3d boxcollider2d not colliding with Vector2.MoveTowards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am moving a sprite that has the following attached BoxCollider2D, Rigidbody2D (Dynamic set with simulated off) and a SpriteRenderer. Problem the trigger is not being set with the following code. I come from a 3D background and this would have triggered but its not in 2D not sure why, maybe things are different?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MonsterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MonsterInformation info;
    private bool isMoving;
    private Vector3 wantedPosition;
    private Vector3 MaxPosition;
    private Vector3 MinPosition;
    private bool isAttacking;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        info = MonsterDatabase.Instance.MonsterLookup("Slime");
        MaxPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x + info.WanderingDistance, 
transform.position.y + info.WanderingDistance, transform.position.z);
        MinPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x - info.WanderingDistance, 
transform.position.y - info.WanderingDistance, transform.position.z);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if(!isMoving)
        {
            wantedPosition.x = Random.Range(MinPosition.x, MaxPosition.x);
            wantedPosition.y = Random.Range(MinPosition.y, MaxPosition.y);
            wantedPosition.z = transform.position.z;
            isMoving = true;
        }
        if(isAttacking)
        {
            return;
        }
         transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, wantedPosition, 
 Time.deltaTime * info.WalkingSpeed);
        if(transform.position == wantedPosition)
        {
            isMoving = false;
        }
     }

     public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         Debug.Log($"Triggered {other.name}");
     }
 }
```

> I am guessing that this needs to be moved through physics? transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, wantedPosition,
> Time.deltaTime * info.WalkingSpeed);

Also thank you for your time to respond to this question even if it seems like its stupid and I didn't do enough research, the main problem is Unity3D in a 3D environment I would collide with a box collider without having to move through physics so I am stumped as to why its not working in 2D.

Comment: It usually seems to be an issue with how the Unity scene is set up rather than code, have you tried enabling simulation on the rigidbody and setting it to "Kinematic" instead?

Comment: I'll give that a go thank you

Comment: That worked trying to figure out how to upvote your answer.

Comment: I was logged into the wrong profile, thank you for your help @Gen